# Need to identify an algorithm to maximize a value

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I come from an engineering background, but I have experience in programming and I have recently come upon a problem which I believe could be optimized. I will do my best to state the problem and hopefully someone can guide me to some sort of standard algorithm which I can implement for this problem. Or at least a starting point so I can modify something and implement it.

> Given **n** items, each with value **s** in dollars for example, I need to create **N** collections of these items, each collection must contain either 40 or 50 items with individual sums 500 dollars or more, and 600 dollars or more respectively. Each collection has a value in dollars, not equal to the individual sum of the items, for example **N(40)** values at 10 dollars, and **N(50)** values at 20 dollars. My interest is to ultimately sum all **N(x)** and maximize that value.

I feel like a naive approach won't help much because I have datasets up too 300-400 items. Is there something that could help me out there?

Comment: just did not understand this point `Each collection has a value in dollars, not equal to the individual sum of the items`

Comment: also can you paste a sample of input ?

Comment: (Linear) Integer-programming is a natural approach here.

Comment: I would guess this could be modeled as a network flow problem.

Comment: Unless there is *some relationship* between the value of a collection of items and the value of the items in that collection, then the naive approach is absolutely the best you can do -- since in any approach that doesn't examine some particular combination of 40 items, perhaps it would turn out that that combination of items is worth $1 million.